# defining __call__ on a class as the constructor

Tags: python-2.7, class

I'm trying to use `__call__` in a way that I'm not sure about the impacts.

I working with a base code data uses **import** to return an arbitrary item from a module like this:

```
try:
    mod = __import__(mod_name, globals(), locals(), [object_name])
finally:
    sys.path.remove(search_folder)

# object_name is a global variable in the module
return getattr(mod, object_name)
```

Currently, each module would define a class and a function. The function in question would just create a new instance of the same class defined in the module, passing all given parameters to the class constructor.

To attempt to avoid copy/paste this function, changing only the call to the class, I defined a superclass with a **call** method, and inside that method I call the same class constructor, like this:

```
class foobar(Object):
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
    def __call__(cls, one, two):
        return cls(one, two)
```

It seems to be working on my tests cases, but I'm not sure the impacts of using such design.
I should add that I have the restriction of not changing the current base code (I tried first with `@staticmethod` but it didn't work).

On the other hand, I don't have a requirement to define modules as that (class with `__call__` method), the main objective is to apply DRY. I'm not familiar with Python meta programming, maybe it would be a more elegant solution?

Comment: Why is `foobar` inheriting from `one` and `two`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I fixed!

Comment: As I read this, `func_in_module = functools.partial(generic_func, class_to_create, *constructor_args, **constructor_kwargs)` is a solution. If not, please clarify ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I think it's worth testing, but I gave it a thought and maybe it won't. Here the original function:

`def foobar_factory(caller, name, config, idx, bar=None): if bar is None:            raise ValueError("No bar was given") return MyClass(caller, name, config, idx, bar=bar)`

So, basically, I don't think it would work because partial is expecting a generic function, which I could provide and a class name, which I can't modify the base code to provide.

As you can see in the same, the class name is hard coded.

Comment: Don't forget that classes are first order objects. You can pass the class object as a parameter to the generic function and use `partial()` to fix it (creating a new function).